# Prevent submit on route change Formik AutoSave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, formik

My app has form with [`<AutoSave/>`](https://twitter.com/jaredpalmer/status/1134141652191404033?s=20) component. This component calls submit once form values were changed. Everything works well but when changing the route it changes form values and `<AutoSave/>` calls submit. How to solve this problem? A possible solution is to mount `<AutoSave/>` again when changing the route.

> [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bouman-7h663)

**AutoSave:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik'
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

const AutoSave = ({ debounceMs }) => {
  const formik = useFormikContext()

  const debouncedSubmit = useCallback(
    debounce(formik.submitForm, debounceMs),
    [formik.submitForm, debounceMs]
  )

  useEffect(() => debouncedSubmit, [debouncedSubmit, formik.values])

  return <>{!!formik.isSubmitting && "saving..."}</>
}
```

**My app:**

```
const App: FC = () => {
  const {books} = getBooks() // [{id: 1, title: 'test', summary: 'test'}, ...]
  const {query} = useRouter()

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(async values => {
    try {
      await API.patch('/books', {id: query.book, ...values})
    } catch (e) {}
  }, [query.book])

  return (
    <>
      <span>Books</span>
      {books.map(({id, title}, key) => (
        <Link key={key} href='/book/[book]' as={`/book/${id}`}>
          <a>{title}</a>
        </Link>
      ))}
      {query.book && (
        <MainForm  
         book={books.find(book => book.id === query.book)}
         handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

**MainForm:**

```
type Props = {
  book: BookProps // {id: string, title: string ...},
  handleSubmit: (values) => Promise<void>
}

const MainForm: FC<Props> = ({book, handleSubmit}) => (
  <Formik 
    enableReinitialize 
    initialValues={{title: book.title, summary: book.summary}}
    handleSubmit={values => handleSubmit(values)}>
    {() => (
      <Form>
        //...My fields...
        <AutoSave debounceMs={500}/> // <=== AutoSave with debounce
      </Form>
    )}
  </Formik>
)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to get the form values with `enableReinitialize = true` on your formik props. Since you have states on the top of your component, it rerenders due to a new value.

Comment: @Lhew, hi! I added `enableReinitialize` to the form but it is not key to solve this problem. Maybe I need to compare prev and next query `book` id and then mount AutoSave again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-sun-057vy

```
# Problem

useEffect(() => debouncedSubmit, [debouncedSubmit, formik.values]);
```

`formik.values` will always change even when the component mounts. That is why `debouncedSubmit` gets called on route change.

So basically, we don't want to run it as component first rendering but when the form is made changes by user.

`formik.dirty` is the key. Just check for `formik.dirty` before doing submit.

```
const AutoSave = ({ debounceMs }) => {
  const formik = useFormikContext();

  const debouncedSubmit = useCallback(
    debounce(formik.submitForm, debounceMs),
    [formik.submitForm, debounceMs]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    formik.dirty && debouncedSubmit();
  }, [debouncedSubmit, formik.dirty, formik.values]);

  return <>{!!formik.isSubmitting && 'saving...'}</>;
};
```

Another thing is the Formik instance. This `Formik` will be used for all the books.
So, you will need to reset the form when binding a new book into it, by using `enableReinitialize` [prop](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik#enablereinitialize-boolean).

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={{ title: book.title, summary: book.summary, id: book.id }}
  onSubmit={values => handleSubmit(values)}
>
```

Or use seperated instances for each book with `key={book.id}`

```
<Formik
  key={book.id}
  initialValues={{ title: book.title, summary: book.summary, id: book.id }}
  onSubmit={values => handleSubmit(values)}
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something like `firstSubmit`, where you check if `firstSubmit` already happened, so it only calls `AutoSave` on the second submit (where it actually changed).

```
const AutoSave = ({debounceMs}) => {
    const [firstSubmit, setFirstSubmit] = React.useState(false)
    const formik = useFormikContext();

    const debouncedSubmit = React.useCallback(
      debounce(firstSubmit ? formik.submitForm : () => setFirstSubmit(true), debounceMs),
      [debounceMs, formik.submitForm, firstSubmit, setFirstSubmit]
    );

    React.useEffect(debouncedSubmit , [debouncedSubmit, formik.values]);

    return <>{!!formik.isSubmitting ? 'saving...' : null}</>;
}
```

I'm not sure if the code works, I haven't tested it yet, because I'm not sure where `debounce` comes from, but the logic is that.

You should check if it already have submited once, and if so, skip it, only submiting when is the second time.

If you provide a working example, I can test it and make it work if the code above doens't work.

Comment: I recreated working example but looks like `<AutoSave/>` works incorrectly there - https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bouman-7h663

Comment: @Arthur your example have other problems that aren't related to `AutoSave`.

Comment: Fixed, you can check now, by the way I took old version of AutoSave

Comment: Formik keeps count of form submission in props formik.submitCount you don't need to set state separately